# css font-size is smaller in apple mail than gmail (iphone)

Tags: html, css, iphone, font-size

I'm doing an html newsletter and the font size result is really different between apple mail and gmail (both on iphone). Apple mail has a really small letter but if I increase it in gmail it looks huge. How can I solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you, write any other tags which you use in your mail.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Another alternative is to set the value of `-webkit-text-size-adjust` to `100%` instead of `none`, so that you will preserve the possibility for the user to zoom.